# displaying only first message from if else condtition

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I am creating a function for coin flip game. but only first msg is displaying again and again from if else condition.

```js
var msgDisplay = document.getElementById('msg-of-game');
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let selectedOptions = document.getElementById('toss').value;
  let coinSides = ["Head", "Tail"];
  let randomToss = coinSides[Math.floor(Math.random() * coinSides.length)];
  console.log(randomToss);
  if(selectedOptions == coinSides){
    console.log('You win !!');
    msgDisplay.innerHTML = 'You win !!';
  }
  else{
    msgDisplay.innerHTML = 'Sorry, You lost it\nBetter luck next time !';
    console.log('Sorry, You lost it\nBetter luck next time !');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box7" id="box7">
    <div class="select-options">
        <h1>Try your Luck !</h1>
        <select name="toss" id="toss">
            <option value="Choose-option">Choose Option</option>
            <option value="head">Head</option>
            <option value="tail">Tail</option>
        </select>
        <button id="check">Check</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-coin">
        <h1 id="msg-of-game"></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: really, so `document.getElementById('toss').value` is `"Head, Tail"` -add your HTML, then we'll see the problem

Comment: Please show us your html code, what is document.getElementById('toss') and how is the value stored.

Comment: <div class="box7" id="box7">
        <div class="select-options">
            <h1>Try your Luck !</h1>
            <select name="toss" id="toss">
                <option value="Choose-option">Choose Option</option>
                <option value="head">Head</option>
                <option value="tail">Tail</option>
            </select>
            <button id="check">Check</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flip-coin">
            <h1 id="msg-of-game"></h1>
        </div>
    </div>

Answer (score 1):

two little issues of note. Firstly you should compare `selectedOptions` to `randomToss` rather than to `coinSides` which is an array. Also, when comparing the two values as mentioned there was a case discrepency  - so by converting both to either upper or lower case should help.

```js
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let selectedOptions = document.getElementById('toss').value.toLowerCase();
  if( selectedOptions==document.getElementById('toss').options[0].value )return;
  
  let coinSides = ["Head", "Tail"];
  let randomToss = coinSides[ Math.floor( Math.random() * coinSides.length ) ].toLowerCase();
  

 
  if( selectedOptions == randomToss ){
    msg='You win !!';
  } else {
    msg='Sorry, You lost it\nBetter luck next time !';
  }
  
  document.getElementById('msg-of-game').innerHTML=msg;
  console.log(msg)
});
```

```html
<div class="box7" id="box7">
    <div class="select-options">
        <h1>Try your Luck !</h1>
        <select name="toss" id="toss">
            <option value="Choose-option">Choose Option</option>
            <option value="head">Head</option>
            <option value="tail">Tail</option>
        </select>
        <button id="check">Check</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-coin">
        <h1 id="msg-of-game"></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

An alternative version that uses the more commonly accepted random number function.

```js
const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);

const clickhandler=function(e){
  const mt_rand=(a,b)=>Math.floor( Math.random() * ( b - a + 1 ) + a );

  let select=q('[name="toss"]');
  let h1=q('.flip-coin > h1');
  let coin={
    1:'Head',
    0:'Tail'
  };
  let i=mt_rand( 0, Object.keys( coin ).length - 1 );
  let result=( Number( select.value )==i ) ? 1 : 0;
  let msg=result ? 'You win !!' : 'Sorry, You lost.\nBetter luck next time!';
    
  h1.textContent=msg;
  console.log(
    'You selected:"%s" - Tossed:"%s" - Result:"%s"',
    select.options[select.selectedIndex].text, 
    coin[i], 
    msg
  )
}

q('.select-options button').addEventListener('click',clickhandler);
```

```html
<div class="box7">
    <div class="select-options">
        <h1>Try your Luck !</h1>
        <select name="toss">
            <option select hidden disabled>Choose Option
            <option value=1>Head
            <option value=0>Tail
        </select>
        <button>Check</button>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-coin">
        <h1></h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for telling me. I forgot to compare with it.Now it's working

Comment: This is not a completely working example... ````Math.random() * coinSides.length```` is not correct, don't multiply with the length and also don't use Math.floor here, you only want ````Math.random()```` with a ````> 0.5```` check.  The only reason this seems like it's working is because it's multiplying with 2, so sometimes it will random 0.8 and multiply it to 1.6 and then floor it to 1, which isn't what you want here.

Comment: indeed - taken directly from the original. I'll add the random number function I use to offer a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all, you receive the else message and not the first message like you have assumed.
I think you want to compare the selectedOption with the randomToss and not a specific value, right? that's how a coin flipping game works.

You are comparing a string with an array of two elements, no wonder you never get true back. Also compare with triple ===, so you can also compare the type. Its a good habit.

Additionally the value you get from html is not starting with a captial letter, so you gotta fix that too.

So after fixing the capital letter problem and comparing the selectedOptions with randomToss you should be good to go. Keep in mind JS is case sensitive.

Working example in snippet:

```js
var msgDisplay = document.getElementById('msg-of-game');
document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', () => {
  let selectedOptions = document.getElementById('toss').value;
  let coinSides = ["head", "tail"];
  let randomToss = coinSides[Math.floor(Math.random() * coinSides.length)];
  console.log('Random Toss:', randomToss);
  console.log('selected options:', selectedOptions);
  if(selectedOptions === randomToss){
    console.log('You win !!');
    msgDisplay.innerHTML = 'You win !!';
  }
  else{
    msgDisplay.innerHTML = 'Sorry, You lost it\nBetter luck next time !';
    console.log('Sorry, You lost it\nBetter luck next time !');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="box7" id="box7"> <div class="select-options"> <h1>Try your Luck !</h1> <select name="toss" id="toss"> <option value="Choose-option">Choose Option</option> <option value="head">Head</option> <option value="tail">Tail</option> </select> <button id="check">Check</button> </div> <div class="flip-coin"> <h1 id="msg-of-game"></h1> </div> </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you should call index 0 for IF condition like this:

```
if(selectedOptions == coinSides[0]){
console.log('You win !!');
msgDisplay.innerHTML = 'You win !!';
}
```